# Why My Card View have very long margin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

simple question , 
why my Card View have long Margin bettween other list ?

[image: Long Margin]

this is my code
**card.xml**
    `

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imagePasar" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Material Design is stunning!!!"
            android:id="@+id/namaPasar" />

    </LinearLayout>


 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`

and heres the mainLayout that used in the mainActivity

**MainLayout**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context="id.web.gosoft.pasarwiki.MainActivity"
  tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RecViewListPasar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Some of the tags in your layout are missing. Can you include those?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. This will scale your image using [Fill](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#FILL). Read [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/) guide for more help.